# Coding with an encrypted Source Code. Possible or Not?

Tags: c#, .net

I created a simple SFX application which works on Compressing / Packing files. When someone click the output file he will be prompted for a password, if password entered correctly the file decrypt it self following a specific routines.

A customer said that my file was a virus, so i scanned the file online on VirusTotal.com and i seen that the file was detected by avira in the [SCAN RESULT](https://www.virustotal.com/file/06e5c80447fad6c43617dc181191bb8cf54803586f27569202ffc24e72d8e7f0/analysis/). I reexamined the source code Line by Line, and i found that the following Lines of code are detected.

```
    public class SimplerAES
    {

        private static byte[] key = { 88, 54, 54, 147, 99, 201, 41, 80, 58, 100, 5, 64, 213, 99, 14, 15, 154, 35, 110, 36, 124, 25, 115, 23, 56, 44, 65, 7, 45, 254, 1, 54 };
        private static byte[] vector = { 33, 8, 121, 196, 223, 45, 63, 100, 1, 32, 18, 87, 1, 158, 119, 111};
        private ICryptoTransform encryptor, decryptor;
        private UTF8Encoding encoder;

        public SimplerAES()
        {
            RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
            encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);
            decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);
            encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        }

        public string Encrypt(string unencrypted)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(encoder.GetBytes(unencrypted)));
        }

        public string Decrypt(string encrypted)
        {
            return encoder.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted)));
        }


        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer)
        {
            MemoryStream encryptStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(encryptStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            return encryptStream.ToArray();
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] buffer)
        {
            MemoryStream decryptStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(decryptStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            return decryptStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

What i want to do now is to find a solution which let me encrypt the class above, so instead of writing it as it is in my C# propgram i will write the encrypted string. and use a function which decrypt and execute the encrypted string at Run-time. So instead of writing the above class i will write the following

```
       String MYCODE = "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"
```

Then simply i call a function like:

```
      xor_get_and_execute_original_code(MYCODE,mykey);
```

Is this possible, and how can I achieve this in the case it is.

Comment: what is the purpose of encrypting this?  if you are trying to protect your code look at obfuscation instead.

Comment: So you mean you want to destroy the maintainability, readability, performance and security of your program because of an obvious false positive of one antivirus?

Comment: @mohamed maache: so your file is a code file?

Comment: the purpose of crypting these line of code is that antivir flag each of my output file as a virus. and this problem is caused by these line of code. I think because most virus writers use these encryption routines in order to obfuscate malware. and therefor antivir can't distingue wether the file is a malware or goodware.

Comment: @ken2k exactly what i want to achieve

Comment: How do you know this part of your code is detected as a virus? Encrypting your binaries will make a false positive more likely rather than less. If you're worried about people reverse engineering your code you could use an obfuscator instead, such as [dotfuscator](http://preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview).

Comment: @Tigran i didn't undertstand what you want to say with code file. but i want to code using encrypted code which decrypts on runtime instead of plain text code.

Comment: Don't you think that your query will result in being more seen like a virus than it is now ?

Comment: I tried to commentout line by line and rescan again, and i discovered the exact lines of code which makes a false postive.

Comment: It’s a pity that this question was closed, and with such a ridiculous reason. Of course this is a *real*, legitimate question. But Michael is right: you are asking for self-modifying code and this would set off every single competent AV scanner at once.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: +1. Absolutely agree. The question also kind of unique. Didn't meet something similiar yet. +1 to OP too.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree, this shouldn't have been closed IMO. Maybe reopen votes would be a good idea?

Comment: @ken2k I thought a mod’s vote was overriding and final. Huh, apparently not.

Comment: you know that the way you do your encryption/decryption is the worst possible? (saving the key easily readable inside your application and using always the same vector ....) - I really don't get what the password should be used for - normaly you will generate the key from the password....

Comment: Yeehay, don't bother encrypting. We know your key now

Comment: Just submit the false postive to Avira.  There is no reason to change your code if it currently works.

Comment: You asked about encrypting your *source code*, but that doesn't make any sense.  Your compiled executable doesn't contain the source code, it contains .NET CIL bytecode, and *that's* what the antivirus software is scanning.

Comment: Your idea is good: If you have a problem with false detection, then change your code to hide it from the detector. People obsessed with maintainability as if it is a mystical cardinal virtue. It is not. It is simply a requirement that only becomes important if your code needs to adapt. If your solution is perfect now and forever, or even the cost of rewriting the encrypted portion of your code is small, do exactly as you say. I like your solution.

Comment: In situations like this you should report the false positive to the company, You can upload your file to Avira using [this form](https://analysis.avira.com/en/submit) and you can check the box for " Suspected False Positive (Not Malware)" they will take a closer look at the file and add it to the whitelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it plugin-style.  Load the decrypted code up via CodeDOM and execute it from there.  Plugin behaviour is usually acceptable to AV-ware.

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever think that what trigger the alert may be this keys ?

```
   private static byte[] key = { 88, 54, 54, 147, 99, 201, 41, 80, 58, 100, 5, 64, 213, 99, 14, 15, 154, 35, 110, 36, 124, 25, 115, 23, 56, 44, 65, 7, 45, 254, 1, 54 };
    private static byte[] vector = { 33, 8, 121, 196, 223, 45, 63, 100, 1, 32, 18, 87, 1, 158, 119, 111};
```

Change them to something different and check it again. I do not see anything else that can trigger the virus alert here.

unfortunately some times the virus or other security check programs can false trigger by "self protection code" that direct read/write on "code memory" of the program, and some of my programs that use HASP or similar protection false trigger the virus. At least two of my programs triggers them with out having any bad code inside, just security test.

Now on this code that I do not see anything that can trigger a virus except a misfortune of combination numbers that's look like a known virus and gives this alert. So ether changes your keys, ether re-position your functions to change this pattern and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if I right understood your trouble, but try to respond:

I just scanned my binary file (C# not obfuscated) on the site provided by you. 
And it passed ok. So may be you can just create a temporary binary file from your code, so no need to encrypt/decrypt of a code-string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that selfextracting (compressed) executables routinely prompt this problem (I have had this happen with a perfectly safe native executable, packed with upx-nrv).

This is because it looks like selfmodifying code (technically it is) and the image won't be easily accessible for inspection (it needs to be decompressed first). I believe the better virus scan software will be able to decompress the image, but in practice it won't be easy, because the EXE packers are frequently marketed as obfuscation tools and emit code to resist reverse-engineering.

In practice it might be hard to unpack the actual image without loading the executable (which is a no-no for a virus scanner, obviously).

Long story short: refrain from using the EXE packer (upx, upx-nrv etc) or live with the 'false' positive.